# Docker Toolbox for Windows:Unable to set experimental flag to true

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-toolbox

I have searched extensively for a solution but I still get the error `ERROR: Dockerfile parse error line 24: Unknown flag: mount`.

I am using Windows 10, so I installed Docker Toolbox and just start using the Docker Quickstart Terminal.

I edited the .config file to set Experimental = true. When I run docker version, the Client side shows experimental = true but the Server shows experimental = false. I tried to look for solutions to access the config file for the server but apparently Docker Server is incompatible with Windows and we use docker-machine instead.

I have also set `# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental` inside my Dockerfile.

Is there any solution to this? Or can I simply replace --mount with -v, would the result be very different?

Answer (score 0):

After much troubleshooting, I downloaded Windows Insider so that I was able to download Docker for Desktop. Apparently it makes your computer slow so just update to version 2004 if possible. With that I was able to make the Experimental setting true for the Docker Engine.